# Уникальный id профиля в URL-адресе

Tags: django, reactjs

хотел бы задать вопрос. Изучаю тему создания профилей. В Фейсбуке и других соц сетях видел подобный URL
: `https://www.facebook.com/people/Larosal%C3%ADa-Smith/pfbid0uyWjc7QWvu4DzuafuoBKYiSNNn97gAciqwjmCHkh8gEzUJM9EzAsmrtgVRDsXtQTl/`, где после `/people/` идет уникальный идентификатор профиля. Очевидно, что это все реализуется в бэкенде на этапе создания профиля: имеется таблица в БД, куда заносятся все идентификаторы профилей (их ID), затем бэкенд просто запрашивает id и отправляет фронтенду. Так как для почти всех аккаунтов пользователей часть `https://www.facebook.com/people/` является идентичной, то предполагаю, что `people` для фейсбука является как раз таким хранилищем id-идентификаторов.

Мне непонятно лишь, как бэкенд может правильно "взять" нужный идентификатор для конкретного профиля?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

> Мне непонятно лишь, как бэкенд может правильно "взять" нужный идентификатор для конкретного профиля?

Если я правильно понял вопрос: при авторизации/регистрации пользователя на бэкенде создается сессия, а в браузер пользователя записывается сессионный cookie. При следующем входе на сайт производится поиск информации о пользователе из этой сессии

https://django.fun/docs/django/5.0/topics/http/sessions/